# How do I get textures to show in render? All answers on google refer to buttons and options i simply dont have

Tags: texturing

I'm trying to add a couple of textures to my scene. One on the sphere and one on the plane in the background. Top right viewing window is 'render' by the way.

I've assigned the texture in edit mode for both.

I've read every tutorial for this I can find and they either end at 'click assign' or go on to talk about options i simply dont have (presumably old version of blender?).

Can anyone tell me what my missing step is here.

(edit:) I assigned the textures by going into 'edit mode' instead of object mode. Clicked on the 'material' button on the right (in picture). Clicked on color and selected 'image texture', chose my png file. The Preview displays correctly (pictured). Clicked on 'Assign' (in between the material lists and the preview). As you can see in the render window, the rectangle plane is showing as black and the sphere is a solid grey instead of their textures.

(edit2:) moonboots got it. i hadnt unwrapped the objects. a instruction suspiciously missing from all the tutorials i read. if anyone else stumbles on this you go into edit mode > mesh > uv unwrap > unwrap.

[image]

Comment: Have you unwrapped your objects? How do your nodes organisations look like?

Comment: When you say you've "assigned the texture in edit mode for both", what do you mean? What steps did you take to do the 'assigning'? Use the [edit] link below your question to add this information please.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos An edit to the question has clarified that this is not the issue.

Comment: If you have a solution to this question this should be put in the answer box below, not as an edit to the question.